# Dynamically export tables in MS Access to CSV

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm wondering is it possible to dynamically export specific MS Access tables to a CSV file using VBA?

I'm able to export all the tables to a CSV / Excel file but the ask I was given once this was in place, is to be able to export a specific set of tables from the MS Access database a CSV file and not the entire set of tables.

Ideally the user would access a Form which they'd be able to select the tables they would like to export and click a button that would run the script.

Is this possible using VBA or is it to complex? Any advice or resources would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But please note, that SO is a forum for code helping, not code writing.

Comment: I'm aware of that and I don't expect a full script to be written for me. I'm just struggling to get to the part where I have a list of all the tables on a form that can be selected and calling this list into an exporting function. Any advice on how to store this list and incorporate it into my exporting function would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider creating a table to list the tables that can be exported, and setting this table as the rowsource of a list box on a form (with multiselect set to Simple/Extended. Then read up on how to loop selected items in a list box. You can then use `DoCmd.TransferText` on each selected item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to populate your listbox:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE ((Left([Name],4)<>"~TMP" And Left([Name],4)<>"MSys" And Left([Name],2)<>"f_") AND ((MSysObjects.Type)=1));
```

To list the tables in VBA:

```
Public Sub enum_tables()
    Dim td As TableDef
    For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" And Left(td.Name, 4) <> "~TMP"  Then
           Debug.Print td.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The matches between the selection in the listbox and the list from 'enum_tables', are the ones you want to export